# RestKit Nested Object of Same Type -- JSON Collection Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I'm using RestKit to pull in comments which may have child comments (and those children may have children, etc).

I am able to pull in depth 0 comments without a problem. I have an array of comment objects for each depth 0 comment. Each parent comment is getting populated with the correct amount of child comments, but all of the properties within the children are nil (only the depth 0 parent is filled in with real data). RestKit gives me the warning:

> W restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:645 WARNING: Detected a relationship mapping  for a collection containing another collection. This is probably not what you want. Consider   using a KVC collection operator (such as @unionOfArrays) to flatten your mappable collection.
>   W restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:646 Key path 'comments.comments' yielded  collection containing another collection rather than a collection of objects:

Also, for each property I'm trying to map in a child, I receive this message (changes by property type)

> E restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:440 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'vote_count' to representation of type 'NSNumber': Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 "Failed transformation of value '(
>   )' to NSNumber: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful." UserInfo=0x8e68280 {detailedErrors=(
>       "Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 \"The given value is not already an instance of 'NSNumber'\" UserInfo=0x8e681e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The given value is not already an instance of 'NSNumber'}",
>       "Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3000 \"Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.\" UserInfo=0x8e68210 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.}" ), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed transformation of value '(
>   )' to NSNumber: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful.}

Despite the warning, I believe it is what I want -- but its struggling with mapping the child objects. It's complaining that it "got an NSArray" when it expected the property type, so I assume I'm doing my property mapping incorrectly.

This is my mapping:

```
+ (RKMapping *) dnCommentMapping {
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DNComment class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"commentId",
                                              @"body": @"body",
                                              @"body_html": @"bodyHTML",
                                              @"created_at": @"createdAt",
                                              @"depth": @"depth",
                                              @"vote_count": @"voteCount",
                                              @"user_id": @"userID",
                                              @"user_display_name": @"userDisplayName",
                                              }];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"comments.comments"
                                                                        toKeyPath:@"comments"
                                                                      withMapping:mapping]];

return mapping;
}
```

Here is my object

```
@interface DNComment : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger commentId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *body;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *bodyHTML;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *created_at;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger depth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger voteCount;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *createdAt;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger userID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userDisplayName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *comments;
@end
```

My RKResponseDescriptor

```
RKMapping *mapping = [DNAMappingProvidor dnCommentMapping];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:/api/v1/stories/1
                                                                                       keyPath:@"story.comments"
                                                                                   statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
```

You can see in the image that depth 0 comment is populated, it creates the correct amount of children (and their children count is correct), but they are not populated.

[image]

Here is an example of the JSON I'm trying to map

```
{
"story": {
"badge": "discussion",
"comment": "THE STORY",
"comments": [
  {
    "body": "THIS IS MY COMMENT - I GET MAPPED FINE",
    "body_html": "<p>THIS IS MY COMMENT - I GET MAPPED FINE</p>\n",
    "comments": [
      {
        "body": "THIS IS MY CHILD RESPONSE - NONE OF MY PROPERTIES GET SET",
        "body_html": "<p>THIS IS MY CHILD RESPONSE - NONE OF MY PROPERTIES GET SET</p>\n",
        "comments": [
          {
            "body": "THIS IS MY CHILD'S CHILD RESPONSE - NONE OF MY PROPERTIES GET SET",
            "body_html": "<p>THIS IS MY CHILD'S CHILD RESPONSE - NONE OF MY PROPERTIES GET SET </p>\n",
            "comments": [

            ],
            "created_at": "2014-02-17T21:07:13Z",
            "depth": 2,
            "id": 41665,
            "url": "https://www.www.com",
            "user_display_name": "A M.",
            "user_id": 201,
            "user_job": "Job Title",
            "user_portrait_url": "image.png",
            "user_url": "user.com",
            "vote_count": 1
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2014-02-17T20:50:05Z",
        "depth": 1,
        "id": 41655,
        "url": "https://www.www.com",
        "user_display_name": "M K.",
        "user_id": 3517,
        "user_job": "Job Title",
        "user_portrait_url": "image.png",
        "user_url": "user.com",
        "vote_count": 2
      }
    ],
    "created_at": "2014-02-17T20:14:47Z",
    "depth": 0,
    "id": 41649,
    "url": "www.www.com",
    "user_display_name": "A M.",
    "user_id": 201,
    "user_job": "Job Title",
    "user_portrait_url": "image.com",
    "user_url": "user.com",
    "vote_count": 32
  },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you issue is just this part:

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"comments.comments"
```

As the from key path should just be `@"comments"`. You don't need to drill down through the structure, RestKit will do that for you as it navigates the JSON applying the mapping.

Comment: I know at one point I had it at just "comments" but that must have been with some other (incorrect) combination. Thank you, what a simple fix!